# Swift making an IBDesignable master container view?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, master-detail, ibdesignable

I am writing an app where I've identified that a single page is used multiple times throughout the app; and I want to use a single UIViewController for this.

Currently I have a UIStoryboard layout;

Storyboard:

`PageA -> PageB -> PageC`

I know that both PageA and PageC are using the same `FactoryListViewController` (any variants are handled in a viewmodel)

This page represents a list of `factories`; has the following components

FactoryListViewController:

- Child ViewController: `HUDViewController` (Has a collection view and some buttons)
- CollectionView (My list of factories)

Knowing this, I want to create a common UIViewController where the child view controllers are `IBDesignable`

but I'm confused as to how to do this because as I understand it, `IBDesignable` is only for UIViews and XIBs, not UIViewController.

My query is this -- how do I make a MasterViewController which itself has ViewControllers and make them IBDesignable?

With thanks

Comment: This sounds like poor design, and yes, that's the reason you are running into the fact that `IBDesignable` is for views, not view controllers. A better MVC pattern would be to - instead of putting a great deal of logic in a view controller - create a "Factory" class with most of that logic in it and let individual controllers use that class. Along with that subclass a container view (or a more suitable UIView), make *it* IBDesignable and use that in IB.

Comment: This sounds like a better plan, I appreciate the viewpoint and assistance, I will give it another go as the storyboards, etc are empty as is easy for me to make adjustments